# Powershell - Remove from Json

Tags: json, powershell

I have the following Json file:

```
{
   "Id":1,
   "Name":"john",
   "Addresses":[
      {
         "Id":1,
         "Street":"1st Street",
         "City":"Riyadh"
      },
      {
         "Id":2,
         "Street":"2nd Street",
         "City":"Dammam"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove the second address in the array using powershell.

I tried the following:

```
 $filePath = 'C:\temp\Settings.json' 
 $settings = $filePath | ConvertFrom-Json

 foreach($item in $settings.Addresses)
 {
      if($item.Id -eq 2)
      {
          $settings.Addresses.Remove($item)
      }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The json posted doesn't look valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *commented* code snippet could help:

```
$filePath = 'C:\temp\Settings.json' 
$settings = Get-Content -Path $filePath | ConvertFrom-Json

# $settings.Addresses               # is an array of fixed size
# $settings.Addresses.IsFixedSize   # returns True
# $settings.Addresses.Remove($item) # isn't possible; hence, let's build new array:

$NewAddresses = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($item in $settings.Addresses)
{
    if ($item.Id -ne 2)
    {
        [void]$NewAddresses.Add( $item )
    }
}

# and replace old one:
$settings.Addresses = $NewAddresses

$settings | ConvertTo-Json  ###  | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Force -Encoding utf8
```

**Output**: `.\SO\66855002.ps1`

```
{
    "Id":  1,
    "Name":  "john",
    "Addresses":  [
                      {
                          "Id":  1,
                          "Street":  "1st Street",
                          "City":  "Riyadh"
                      }
                  ]
}
```